# Convert pointer to int and back to typed object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, casting

I need a simple way to convert a pointer to an int, and then back to the pointer. I need it as an int for portability, since an int is easier to carry around in my project than a pointer.

Start player and return pointer:

```
SoundPlayer* player = new FxPlayerTiny();
return (int)player; // this works, but is it correct?
```

Stop player using pointer int:

```
FxPlayerTiny* player = static_cast<FxPlayerTiny*>((int*)num); // this gives me an error
FxPlayerTiny* player = (FxPlayerTiny*)((int*)obj); // this works, but is it correct?
delete player;
```

Comment: Er, how is int easier to carry around? And no that code isn't safe.

Comment: If you really _really_ have to cast to something opaque, at least use a `void*`.

Comment: Why is an int easier to use than a pointer?  That just sounds wrong.  Also, there are no guarantees a whole pointer will fit in an int.  C provides intptr_t (and most implementations of C++ also provide it) that is an integer type guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer.  Use reinterpret_cast to switch between the two.

Comment: @James: There's no guarantee that `intptr_t` and `uinptr_t` exist; on an implementation where pointers are bigger than the widest supported integer, they won't. But I've never heard of such an implementation. Also, those types were introduced in C99, so older C compilers (and Microsoft's) may not support them.

Comment: Fix your project so it's capable of dealing with pointers directly.

Comment: @James - Can you add a proper implementation with void*?

Comment: @KeithThompson, that's why I said 'most' C++ implementations.  It's actually only optional in the C99 standard (I just found out).  However, even if such a system with pointers larger than the largest integer type exists, the compiler still has to implement pointer arithmetic somehow, so that should never be an issue.

Comment: @Geotarget, void* is a mildly better solution, but not by much. It really depends on what you're doing though. Sometimes void* is an acceptable compromise.

Comment: @James: ISO C++ didn't adopt `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` until the 2011 standard. I don't know how many C++ compilers have added them, either as extensions or as part of C++11 compliance. I'm not sure what you mean by "... so that should never be an issue"; it's certainly an issue in the sense that without them, there's no guaranteed way to convert a pointer to an integer and back again without loss of information. An implementation with huge pointers will certainly provide pointer arithmetic, but perhaps not in a way that's useful for what the OP is asking.

Comment: @KeithThompson, my point was that any compiler is obliged to implement pointer arithmetic for any size of pointer supported by the host system. Therefore, the work needed to implement the arithmetic for any integer type up to the size of a pointer is already done (pointer arithmetic is, essentially, integer arithmetic at the end of the day) and so while it would be possible to just implement the arithmetic for pointers, it doesn't make much sense to just do that if you can also provide integer types (outside of intptr_t) that are equal to the size of a pointer for almost no extra work.

Comment: @James: Integers are not pointers. It's very likely that pointer and integer arithmetic are implemented similarly, but the standard doesn't require or imply that. A system with pointers bigger than 64 bits is likely to be fairly exotic, so such a system is more likely to represent pointers quite differently than integers. (A simple example: a pointer could be a descriptor plus an offset, with arithmetic applying only to the offset.) Furthermore, pointer arithmetic consists only of addition and subtraction; integer arithmetic has to include multiplication and division.

Comment: @KeithThompson, that's only partly true.  Yes, once you have the offset that needs to be applied, pointer arithmetic only consists of addition and subtraction, but calculating that offset will almost always require multiplication - some of which can be done at compile time, some of which must be performed at run time - depending on the circumstances. But we're just arguing semantics now. :)

Comment: @James: Ah, but semantics is what it's all about! If you have 128-bit pointers, you probably only have to perform multiplication on offsets, so you don't need full 128-bit multiplication -- and you don't need 128-bit division at all. Full support for 128-bit pointers could be much easier than full support (+, -, *, /, %, etc.) for 128-bit integers, so it's quite plausible that an implementation could support 128-bit pointers but only 64-bit integers, and thus not be able to define `[u]intptr_t`. (You could have a type that only supports *some* operations -- and call it `void*`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson No, that's a false assumption. If you support 128-bit pointers, you have to support 128-bit offset calculations - including both multiplication and division. You can't arbitrarily only half implement pointer arithmetic. (Well, you can, but then you're not fully implementing the standard if you have something that might not work in all situations.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, I think at the end of the day, you would need a processor architecture that did implement exotic memory addressing with super-sized pointers and also didn't provide add/subtract-with-carry as basic instructions or the means to read carry or overflow status from the flags register. And that system would be so severely limited in what it could do, I'm not sure how practical it would be as far as implementing a C++ compiler is concerned anyway.

Comment: @James: Assume the 128-point pointers consist of a 64-bit descriptor and a 64-bit offset. Integer arithmetic (yes, you need `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`) applies only to the 64-bit offset.  If the platform only supports 64-bit integer arithmetic, everything can work as required -- and you can't define `[u]intptr_t`. (Unless you do 128-bit arithmetic in software, but that slows down code that uses `[u]intmax_t`.) Descriptor values are manipulated *only* when objects are allocated and deallocated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best thing to do is to fix your project so it can deal with pointers. Integers and pointers are two different things. You can convert back and forth, but such conversions can lose information if you're not careful.

Converting a pointer value to `int` and back again can easily lose information, depending on the implementation and the underlying platform. For example, there are systems on `int` is smaller than a pointer. If you have 32-bit `int`s and 64-bit pointers, then converting a pointer to an `int` and back again will almost certainly give you an invalid pointer.

It's very likely that `long` or `unsigned long` is wide enough to hold a converted pointer value without loss of information; I've never worked on a system where it isn't. (Personally, I tend to prefer unsigned types, but not for any really good reason; either should work equally well.)

So you could write, for example:

```
SoundPlayer* player = new FxPlayerTiny();
return reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>player;
```

and convert the `unsigned long` value back to a pointer using `reinterpret_cast,SoundPlayer*>`.

Newer implementations provide typedefs `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`, which are unsigned and signed integer types guaranteed to work correctly for round-trip pointer-to-integer-to-pointer conversions.  They were introduced in C99, and *optionally* defined in the `<stdint.h>` header. (Implementations on which pointers are bigger than *any* integer type won't define them, but such implementations are rare.) C++ adopted them with the 2011 standard, defining them in the `<cstdint>` header. But Microsoft Visual C++ does support them as of the 2010 version.

This guarantee applies only to ordinary pointers, not to function pointers or member pointers.

So if you must do this, you can write:

```
#include <cstdint>
SoundPlayer* player = new FxPlayerTiny();
return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>player;
```

But first, consider this. `new FxPlayerTiny()` gives you a pointer value, and you're going to want a pointer value. If at all possible, just keep it as a pointer. Converting it to an integer means that you have to decide which of several techniques to use, and you have to keep track of which pointer type your integer value is supposed to represent. If you make a mistake, either using an integer type that isn't big enough or losing track of which pointer type you've stored, the compiler likely won't warn you about it.

Perhaps you have a good reason for needing to do that, but if you can just store pointers as pointers your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ has supported `uintptr_t`, `intptr_t`, and `ptrdiff_t` (their always forgotten partner) since at least the 2008 release, probably longer.  :)

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` has been standard since 1989, but it's nice to know that that they support `[u]intptr_t` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use an int for portability, especially because `sizeof (int)` and `sizeof (void*)` could differ (for example when compiling for Windows x64).
If ints are needed for a user interface, it maybe would be better to use a table of pointers and accessing them via indices.

However, if you want to convert an pointer to an integer and vice versa a simple conversion is enough but it's just the same, if `sizeof *int) == sizeof (void*)`.