# assign address of char pointer to int

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I have a function that gets an integer as a parameter. I want to send a char array's address to it, then print the array from its address. I mean:

```
void printSomeThing(int x){
    printf("Variable is: %s\n", /*What to type here?*/);
    //I want this printf to write "file.txt"
}

....

int main(){
    char filename[10] = "file.txt";
    char *filePointer = filename;  //So it points to filename[0]'s address.
    int x = /*How to convert the address of the pointer (or the char array) to an integer?*/
    printSomeThing(x);
}
```

So, I want to send the char array's address to the function and print that address's value.

NOTE: I can't change the `printSomeThing` parameter. It has to be an `int`.

Comment: You can try casting your pointer to an `int` and then back to `char *`, but it may not work (undefined behavior).  On many systems this is impossible, e.g. 64-bit systems where a pointer is 64 bits but `int` is only 32 bits.  The code will compile but most likely crash when you run it.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? The way to pass a pointer value to a function is to use an argument of pointer type.

Comment: The first thing to do is add `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(filePointer), sizeof(x));` to your code. If it prints two different numbers, then you simply cannot do what you're hoping for.

Comment: @NateEldredge is right.  The proper way to do this is to cast your pointer to a `uintptr_t` which was made available in C99 (someone correct me if I'm wrong).  Other than, casting pointers to integers normally leads to Bad Things happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602280/convert-pointer-to-int-and-back-to-typed-object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624737/casting-a-pointer-to-an-int/22624888

Comment: @KeithThompson I want to send the memory address to the function so that I can get its value.

Comment: Yes, obviously that's what you want to do. But if the function needs an address to be passed as an argument, why doesn't the function define its parameter with a pointer type? (There are some rare cases where defining a function with an integer argument that then treats that argument as an address value makes sense. You haven't said anything that indicates why you'd need to do that.)

Comment: Because the function gets an integer and is a general-purpose function. Other functions also pass integers to it. Thank you. @KeithThompson

Comment: But *why* does it take an integer argument? How does it know whether to treat its argument as an integer or as a pointer? The specification in your question makes what you're trying to do pretty much impossible: an `int` often cannot hold a pointer value. On many systems, `int` is 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits. The obvious solution is to have one function that takes an integer and another that takes a pointer. Why exactly would that not meet your requirements? I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to convert between pointer addresses and integers is to use the `uintptr_t` integer type. This is a type guaranteed to be large enough to hold an address (unlike `int`). This code is fairly safe and portable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSomeThing(uintptr_t x){
    printf("Variable is: %s\n", (char*)x);
}

int main(){
    char filename[10] = "file.txt";
    char *filePointer = filename;  //So it points to filename[0]'s address.
    uintptr_t x = (uintptr_t)filePointer;
    printSomeThing(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char*)`, then what you're trying to do is not possible, in general.

However, there is a way to still make this work. Before I tell you how to achieve this, let me reiterate what others have said: **you should not use an int as a pointer.** This is not a good idea. What I am going to demonstrate is just that: a demonstration. Just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be done.

One way to make this work is to map memory at an address smaller than `1 << (sizeof(int) * 8)`. Then, copy the string you want to that memory location. Now, you can pass this pointer to your `printSomething(int)` function.

There is one problem with this solution: it's not portable, so it doesn't always work. I couldn't get it to work with clang on macOS, but it does work [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler). Here is the code I used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

void printSomething(int x){
    printf("Variable is: %s\n", (char*) x);
}

int main(){
    char filename[10] = "file.txt";
    char *allocd = mmap((void*) 0x10000, sizeof(filename)+1,
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    strcpy(allocd, filename);
    printSomething((int) allocd);
}
```

Another solution that should probably only be used as a demonstration is one where you ask gcc to define a section at a low memory address. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128613/13040392) answer does something along those lines. This is probably not portable either.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could think to do this given that you dont want to just pass a pointer to the array - would be to cast it to an unsigned long in order to give it to the function.

However your compiler might complain that you are passing an integer value to a string pattern in printf but that is by virtue of the design you are using.

If you dont need to use `printSomeThing(int i)` then just pass the char* itself or use a void* if you need other things passed through and use some sort of flag to tell the function what type you passed